# Utilizando Sqlite externo na pasta Assets com Fragment

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou utilizando um banco de dados sqlite externo, na pasta assets.

Segui esse modelo ([carregando-um-banco-criado-externamente](http://diegorubin.com/2012/02/19/desenvolvimento-para-android-carregando-um-banco-criado-externamente)) e consegui ter acesso ao banco.

Quanto testei funcionou normalmente no meu MainActivity, o problema que tive foi quando tentei utilizar com Fragment.

No meu projeto estou utilizando fragments, e não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar.

Parte do código que está dentro de um Fragment;

```
    helper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity(),null,1);
    db = helper.getDatabase();

    list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listalivro);
    Cursor cursor = db.query("livro", campos, null, null, null, null, null);
    SimpleCursorAdapter Madapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        cursor,
        new String[] {"ver_livro","ver_capitulo"},
        new int[] {R.id.ver_livro,R.id.ver_capitulo }, 0);

    list.setAdapter(Madapter);
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Lembrando que esse código funcionou quando criei um novo projeto sem fragment, monto tudo na MainActivity.
Ele copia o banco de dados e abre normalmente.
Porém no meu projeto não funciona.

11-23 16:17:19.053: E/Trace(755): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Já me certifiquei que o banco está na pasta assets, não há nenhum firewall ou antivirus barrando o acesso. 
Lembrando que se eu utilizar sem fragment funciona sem problemas.

Comment: Essa classe `DatabaseHelper` é sua ou é uma subclasse de `SQLiteOpenHelper`? Poderia incluir ela na pergunta?